# Timing and Profiling in IPython 2.x

Tags: python, profiling, ipython, memory-profiling

I found the following article: [Timing and Profiling in IPython](http://pynash.org/2013/03/06/timing-and-profiling.html) from March, 2013, but I am having problems defining and using the magics. I wonder if this is because some of the information in the article does not apply anymore.

I did:

```
$ pip install line-profiler
$ pip install psutil
$ pip install memory_profiler
```

and then in my IPython session I defined:

```
import memory_profiler

def load_ipython_extension(ip):
    ip.define_magic('memit', memory_profiler.magic_memit)
    ip.define_magic('mprun', memory_profiler.magic_mprun)
```

When when I then try:

`%memit`

I get: `ERROR: Line magic function not defined`. Why?

Also, is the article from 2013 relevant still for **IPython 2.x**?

Answer (score 1):

You also need to "register the modules", as explained later in the post.

> Edit ~/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py, search for,
>   uncomment, and modify these lists to include:
>
> c.TerminalIPythonApp.extensions = [
>       'line_profiler_ext',
>       'memory_profiler_ext', ] c.InteractiveShellApp.extensions = [
>       'line_profiler_ext',
>       'memory_profiler_ext', ]

This worked for me, when I defined a profile and the extension folder `$IPythonDIR/extensions`.

Not sure, how to make this work if you manually import the functions in the interactive shell.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know what registering the modules does?

Comment: No, I don't. Sorry... I guess this will require the understanding of what the `c.InteractiveShellApp.extensions` do.